# insert value in input form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, insert

When one image is selected ...

```html
<div class="selectable">
  <img src="https://glarza.com/imagens/tamanho-33.webp" class="ui-widget-content"value="SIZE-33"width="60"height="60">
  <img src="https://glarza.com/imagens/tamanho-34.webp" class="ui-widget-content"value="SIZE-34"width="60"height="60">
 </div>
```

this function select the size ...

```js
<script>    
    $(function() {
  $(".selectable").selectable({
    selected: function() {
      var selectedItemList = $("#medida-selecionada-dalista").empty();
      $(".selectable img").each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).hasClass("ui-selected")) {
          selectedItemList.append(
              
              $(this).attr("value") ); } });}});});
    </script>
```

And show the selected size inside the id ...

```html
<span id="medida-selecionada-dalista"></span>
```

My problem... I need to insert this value inside this input. I need only this. The others inputs are storeged in mysql.

```html
 <input type="size" class="form-control" id="size" name="size" value="">
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("size").value = ...` doesn't work?

Comment: FYI: In future posts, rather than break your code up into sections (that can't run by themselves), just make one Stack Snippet with all the code that we can run. Add comments to the code to point things out if needed.

Comment: Does adding spaces help? `class="ui-widget-content" value="SIZE-33" width="60" height="60"`

Answer (score 0):

Like so?

```js
$(function() {
  $(".selectable").selectable({
    selected: function() {
      var selectedItemList = $("#medida-selecionada-dalista").empty();
      $(".selectable img").each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).hasClass("ui-selected")) {
          selectedItemList.append(
            $(this).attr("value")
          );
          /* insert into input */
          document.getElementById("size").value = this.getAttribute("value");
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="size" class="form-control" id="size" name="size" value="">

<span id="medida-selecionada-dalista"></span>

<div class="selectable">
  <img src="https://glarza.com/imagens/tamanho-33.webp" class="ui-widget-content" value="SIZE-33" width="60" height="60">
  <img src="https://glarza.com/imagens/tamanho-34.webp" class="ui-widget-content" value="SIZE-34" width="60" height="60">
</div>
```

P.S. avoid jquery whenever you can...

Comment: Thank you very much. My best regards.
"getElementById" is running perfectly